# How to save spinner selected value (It jumps back to value 0)

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

*** SOLUTION ***

This might not be the perfect solution but definitely working for me :)

Update load()

```
private void load() {

    if (helper.getResults(c).equals("Yes")) {
        spinner.setSelection(0);
    } else if (helper.getResults(c).equals("No")) {
        spinner.setSelection(1);
    }
}
```

Results = your declared helper 
"Yes"/"No" = Your choices 
0 = Yes
1 = No

Update according to your needs

*** UPDATE ***

I actually store the selected spinner into one EditText, then the selected Spinner will capture the value to EditText.
However when I want to edit the database again, instead of showing "No" in the EditText and the Spinner value, it shows "Yes" in EditText and the Spinner Value.

I'm using Spinner to get value (yes and no) and save to SQLite Database.'
Upon pressing save button, the value of the selected spinner is saved into string.

However when the user select "no", when I try to change the data, other values (edittext) is saved, but the Spinner value jumps back to "yes".

I wish that if the user Select "no", when he wants to edit the database it will still appear "no"

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.results);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.categoryET);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Yes");
    list.add("No");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    mMyPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mMyEdit = mMyPrefs.edit();

    spinner.setAdapter(adp);

    int selectedPosition = mMyPrefs.getInt("selected_position", 0) ;
    text.setText(list.get(selectedPosition));
    spinner.setSelection(selectedPosition);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(position) {

                case 0 :
                    text.setText("Yes");
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    text.setText("No");
                    break;
                default :
                    text.setText("Nothing");
                    break;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMyEdit.putInt("selected_position", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            mMyEdit.commit();


        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're re-entering the activity at `onStart()`, if you're doing something different, simply switch `onStart()` for the appropriate entry point.

You'll have to keep track of what the last used variable was, and pass that to the spinner as the set value in `onStart()`.

You have a couple of options for storing last used variable, and they depend on how long you'd like the setting to live. The simplest is per application run, and you would accomplish that by setting the spinners value to your `text` variable in `onStart()`.

The other options would be persistence over multiple runs of the application, and even then you have a couple of options. The most obvious being to use sqlite, since you already are, and hopefully are experienced with it. You could simply add a database entry for the last used variable, and read it in `onStart()`.

Other options include creating files on the internal/external storage, Android's [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), and the others listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Thank you I will look through :)

Comment: Just to clarify on my answer, and just say it since apparently no one has yet: Every time an activity is ran, all of the GUI components (eg. TextView, Spinner, RadioButtons etc.) will be of default value (usually set in XML). It is up to you upon creation or restart to set the correct value to the components if the default is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
private SharedPreferences mMyPrefs;
private Editor mMyEdit;
```

on **onCreate()**:

```
mMyPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mMyEdit = mMyPrefs.edit();


ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    spinner.setAdapter(adp);

int selectedPosition = mMyPrefs.getInt("selected_position", 0) ;
your_edittext.setText(list.get(selectedPosition));
spinner.setSelection(selectedPosition);
```

on **setOnItemSelectedListener()**:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

 mMyEdit.putInt("selected_position", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
 mMyEdit.commit();

 // Other stuff

 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help and I've tried your method, unfortunately doesn't work... what is the mMyEdit? (Because over here I'm using EditText to capture the selected Spinner Value)

Comment: @Michael, mMyEdit is SharedPreference.Editor for put value in shared preference. In my method you will get last selected item position so you can get value from arraylist or array by position and you can set value in edittext.

Comment: For the private Editor mMyEdit; it forces me to import class:   private SharedPreferences.Editor mMyEdit; Is there any thing wrong I've done here?

Comment: @Michael, you have to import 
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code. I've changed int arg2 to int position still does not work.. is there anything i'm missing out?

Comment: @Michael, have edited my answer, please check, make sure you set ontemseleted listener after setadapter.

Comment: It still doesnt work.. is it because of the mMyEdit? because I'm using EditText to display the selected spinner value.

Comment: @Michael, please forget Edittext as of now. Just select spinner than go into next screen again come back to spinner's screen, please check spinner state stay remains or not, if done than let me know i ll provide you code for edittext.

Comment: To clarify, I am able to save into sqldatabase. Just when I wish to update the database, the spinner goes back to default value instead of displaying the saved selected spinner value

Comment: sorry for the late reply! I tried your code and still cant figure out why it doesnt work. I've updated my code

Comment: The code somehow works! Now the problem is whenever the user edit the database, the spinner will be the last recorded value, still not what the user has chosen

Comment: You can add text watcher on edit text and if it matches from database than just setSelection of spinner.

Comment: That might be a challange for me, I'm a novice at android.. I'll try to researchon that! :)

Comment: Hi! I've found a solution and it's working as above code! Thank you for your great help :)